# using a repeater within a repeater working with xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

i have an xml document structured like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
    <videos>
      <video>
        <name>name of video</name>
      </video>
    </videos>
    <videos>
      <video>
        <name>name of video</name>
      </video>
    </videos>
</NewDataSet>
```

i want to be able to use a repeater within a repeater to edit some of the values stored in the different nodes.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet videos = new DataSet();


    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("/my.xml"));

    XmlNodeList nodes =
       doc.SelectNodes("NewDataSet/videos");

    rptVideosList.DataSource = nodes;
    rptVideosList.DataBind();
}
protected void videoRepeater_ItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        XmlNode video = (XmlNode)e.Item.DataItem;
        Repeater rptvideo = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptVideoList");
        rptvideo.DataSource = video.ChildNodes;
        rptvideo.DataBind();
    }
}


<asp:Repeater ID="rptVideosList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="videoRepeater_ItemBound">
            <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <div style="border:solid 1px red; clear:both;">
            videos
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptVideoList" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    video
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

this just seems to be showing the 'videos' nodes but not the 'video' nodes. ie the front end just shows this:

videos
videos

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong inner repeater layout

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                    video
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
```

Remove one `<ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>`

Comment: hi IceN, thaks for replying, ive removed this extra itemtemplate but the result is still the same

Comment: I've tested into my VS and everything works as expected. I have this code of inner repeater   <asp:Repeater ID="rptVideoList" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    video
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater> If it doesn't help i could share my vs project.

Comment: STRANGE, YES PLEASE. is there a way to share files through stackoverflow?